# Passing variables around after authentication with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, session-variables

I am creating a website that integrates with Facebook's graph API using the PHP SDK. However, i am looking for a way i can pass variables like user id, location, likes etc between pages (maybe using php's session_start. And when the user logs out of facebook the session gets deleted.
Thanks.

Comment: please be specific on problem you are facing. where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The session needs to be managed by your php application. Once facebook authenticates you using it's API you are given an access token for further requests using the graph api. Facebook doesn't authenticate you again and again. The session and the params that you need are the responsibility of you application. If you want to interact with facebook data, you use graph API in that case, else your application runs independently.